# Checking if a string is NOT part of an Array (C#, Linq)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to use Linq to determine if a string is NOT in an array. The code I'm using is:

```
if (!stringArray.Any(soughtString.Contains)){
            doStuff();}
```

but it's not working. Obviously creating a foreach loop would suffice, but I'd like to understand why this line isn't working. And yes, the file has `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `array.Contains("foo")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not asking if the string is not in the array, you're asking if none of the strings in the array are sub-strings in some other string.  Apparently at least one is, even though it's not equal.

You just want to do a simple `Contains` check:

```
if(!stringArray.Contains(soughtString))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are currently passing the "Any" function the "Contains" method (which is then being passed  each string in the array). In other, words:

```
array.Any(s => soughtString.Contains(s));
```

Likely, you want it the other way:

```
array.Any(s => s.Contains(soughtString));
```